# I can only cast a contravariant delegate with "as"

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0, casting, contravariance

I'm trying to cast a contravariant delegate but for some reason I can only do it using the "as" operator.

```
interface MyInterface { }
delegate void MyFuncType<in InType>(InType input);

class MyClass<T> where T : MyInterface
{
    public void callDelegate(MyFuncType<MyInterface> func)
    {
        MyFuncType<T> castFunc1 = (MyFuncType <T>) func; //Error
        MyFuncType<T> castFunc2 = func as MyFuncType<T>; 
        MyFuncType<T> castFunc3 = func is MyFuncType<T> ? (MyFuncType<T>)func : (MyFuncType<T>)null; //Error
    }
}
```

castFunc2 works fine but castFunc1 and castFunc3 cause the error:

```
Cannot convert type 'delegateCovariance.MyFuncType<myNamespace.MyInterface>' to myNamespace.MyFuncType<T>'
```

The [MSDN article on the as operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) states that castFunc2 and castFunc3 are "equivalent" so I don't understand how only one of them could cause an error. Another piece of this that is confusing me is that changing MyInterface from an interface to a class gets rid of the error.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?
Thanks!

Comment: This compiles fine for me here: http://ideone.com/5SjUxV Am I missing something? (not the most familiar with ideone). I get the stated error if I remove `in` from the `MyFuncType` declaration.

Comment: hmm. I thought that maybe you weren't getting the erros because ideone uses mono but I tried using mono from visual studio and I am still getting the errors.

Comment: @rob I used mono targeting .Net 4 and got no errors. Which version of the .Net framework are you targeting?

Comment: @mike z. I am also targeting .Net 4.0. I just did a fresh install of Mono 2.10.8 and followed these instructions for using it from VS http://erictummers.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/target-mono-from-visual-studio/ . Are you saying that you didn't get any errors from Visual Studio or from ideone?

Comment: @rob I ran it on mono 2.10.8.1 on ubuntu and I received no errors in monodevelop and was able to execute without exception. However, in VS 2010 targeting .Net 4 I do indeed get the compiler errors you cite.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Add a constraint such that T must be a class.**

```
class MyClass<T> where T: class, MyInterface
```

This gives the compiler enough information to know that T is convertible. You don't need the explicit cast either.

**Variance only applies to reference types. T is allowed to be a value type without the constraint which breaks the compilers ability to prove that T is compatible for contravariance.**

The reason the second statement works is because `as` actually can perform a null conversion. For example:

```
class SomeClass { }
interface SomeInterface { }
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   SomeClass foo = null;
   SomeInterface bar = foo as SomeInterface;
}
```

`Foo` is obviously not directly convertable to `SomeInterface`, but it still succeeds because a null conversion can still take place. Your MSDN reference may be correct for most scenarios, but the generated IL code is very different which means they are fundamentally different from a technical perspective.

Comment: +1. You could also do this to avoid the compiler error: `MyFuncType<T> castFunc1 = (MyFuncType <T>)(object)func;` but that will blow up at run-time for value types anyway, so this is a better solution.

Comment: **Good explanation.** Regarding your last example: Here, with no generics, an explicit cast would also compile. That is `bar = (SomeInterface)foo` would be allowed compile-time. However, when a generic parameter like `T` is involved, the compiler is more strict. This is to help people not mis-use generics and do excessive casting. Note in your `foo`/`bar` example that it is very important that `SomeClass` is unsealed. If it were `sealed` the compiler would know that a `SomeClass` could never be a `SomeInterface`.

Answer (score 4):

Eric Lippert gave a great explanation of this issue in his recent posts: [An "is" operator puzzle, part one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/08/23/an-quot-is-quot-operator-puzzle-part-one.aspx), [An "is" operator puzzle, part two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/08/27/an-quot-is-quot-operator-puzzle-part-two.aspx).

Main rationale behind this behavior is following: "is" (or "as") operators are not the same as a cast. 
"as" operator can result non-null result event if corresponding cast would be illegal, and this is especially true when we're dealing with type arguments.

Basically, `cast` operator in your case means (as Eric said) that **"I know that this value is of the given type**, even though the compiler does not know that, the compiler should allow it" or **"I know that this value is not of the given type**; generate special-purpose, type-specific code to convert a value of one type to a value of a different type."

Later case deals with value conversions like double-to-integer conversion and we can ignore this meaning in current context.

And generic type arguments are not logical in the first context neither. If you're dealing with a generic type argument, than why you're not stating this "contract" clearly by using generic type argument?

I'm not 100% sure what you're want to achieve, but you can omit special type from your method and freely use generic argument instead:

```
class MyClass<T> where T : MyInterface
{
    public void callDelegate(Action<T> func)
    {
    }
}

class MyClass2
{
    public void callDelegate<T>(Action<T> func)
        where T : MyInterface
    {
    }
}
```

Otherwise you should use `as` operator with check for null instead of type check.

Answer (score -1):

Your class says that `T` implements `MyInterface` because `MyInterface` is not a instance type.  Therefore, `MyFuncType<T>` is not guaranteed to be `MyFuncType<MyInterface>`.  It could be `MyFuncType<SomeType>` and `SomeType : MyInterface`, but that wouldn't be the same as `SomeOtherType : MyInterface`.  Make sense?

Comment: "`MyFuncType<T>` is not guaranteed to be `MyFuncType<MyInterface>`" That's true, but I think you're confusing casting with assignment.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Didn't realize I messed it up.  No confusion on casting and assignment here.  My point is that generics are templates and `T` will never be guaranteed to be `MyInterface`.